# Is it possible to download the code of a web app you've created in Esri's Web AppBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I've created an app in Esri's Web AppBuilder, but now I'd like to download the code and host it myself.  I have both ArcGIS Online and ArcGIS Server.  In the past, there was a "Publish" option where you could download your code, but it seems to have disappeared in the new version.

EDIT: I can manually pull some HTML and JavaScript off the page using Chrome and the "Inspect Element" tool (via the "Sources" tab).  However, even when structured the same and hosted, the app doesn't fully load (the progress bar stops at about 75%).  I'm familiar with web concepts and I would think this should work, but I must be missing something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is accessible via the homepage of your Web App Builder. Highlight your map then hit the ellipsis at the right-hand side of the page, and there's a Download option.

[image]

Unzip the resulting files into your web server directory (eg `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` on a PC, `/Library/WebServer/Documents` on a Mac, etc)

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more specific.  It appears that you are using the developer version of Web AppBuilder.  I'm trying to do this through the Web AppBuilder that's hosted at <organization>.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappbuilder (this may not be possible).

Comment: I downloaded the developer edition of Web AppBuilder (as I really should have done in the first place) and got it to work per your instructions.  Thank you!  I'm going to leave the question as unanswered for now to see if anyone knows how to do it through ArcGIS Online, but will accept your reply as the answer.  Thanks again!

Comment: Not sure about that, sorry!

Answer (score 2):

I believe it can be done the way you originally intended to: From the "My Content" area of ArcGIS Online select the "View item details" option for your Web Mapping Application. In the page that opens there is a "Download" link in the Properties section.

Comment: I just tested this and it worked for me perfectly. I just got back from the Dev Summit and they discussed this as an option. You can create your Web Apps in Developer or ArcGIS and pass them back and forth (assuming both are same version).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot download the WAB application from your ArcGIS Online My Content page. However, when having WAP (Dev edition) installed, you can import the application you have in your organization. This will pull the application from your ArcGIS Online to your machine.

On the home page, click Import and choose Import from my account to open Import App window. It displays available apps created by Web AppBuilder integrated in your portal.

Help page: https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/guide/create-import-app.htm